# Laravel | same button with different functions

Tags: laravel, button, modal-dialog

I have two buttons that will open a modal, but I don't know how to differentiate them to open the right modal.
It's an accept button and a reject button.

```xml
<a id='aceitar' href="{{route('despesas.modal', $item)}}">
  <i class="fas fa-check text-info mr-1"></i>
</a>
<a href="{{route('despesas.modal2', $item)}}">
  <i class="fas fa-ban text-danger mr-1"></i>
</a>
```

Modal acept

```php
<?php 
  if (@$id != "") {
    echo "<script>$('#modalaceitar').modal('show');</script>";
  }
?>
```

modal reject

```php
<?php 
  if (@$id != "") {
    echo "<script>$('#modalrejeita').modal('show');</script>";
  }
?>
```

Do I have any way to differentiate them? Because both check if the ID is different from empty

```
if (@$id != "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `data` attribute to target the required modal.

```html
<button class="open-modal" data-target="modal-a">Modal A</button>
<button class="open-modal" data-target="modal-b">Modal B</button>

<div id="modal-a" class="hidden">Modal A</div>
<div id="modal-b" class="hidden">Modal B</div>
```

The `.hidden` class applied above simply sets the `css` `display` property to `none`.

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Then using some JavaScript, you can apply `click` `event` handlers to each `button` by using `querySelectAll` to find all `button` elements with the given `class` name and then when a `button` is clicked, read the `data-target` dataset and `toggle` (or `remove`) the `display` property for that `modal`.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.open-modal');

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.target).classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
});
```

[Example JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0xnsjgch/)

Comment: By putting this way the modal "runs away" to a page background. By placing this code
class="hidden"